# For some reason, margin: 0 auto isn't working (height isn't infinite)

Tags: html, css

http://talk.thegoodhumor.com/

As you can see here, the height just isn't continuous and I have no idea why.

I've toyed with it for quite a while now, and I am still baffled.

Comment: Eh there, margin:0 auto helps you center-align fixed width elements, it won't help you with 'infinite height'. Do you want the container div to be infinite in height?

Comment: Do you mean the text? If so, it's because you have vertical-align: middle, with content that sometimes wraps to two lines and sometimes doesn't.

If you don't mean the text, it's not clear what you mean. All boxes have the same height for me. Paste in the particular code you're working with and we'll try to help.

Comment: Yes, Amit G. Sorry for the confusion everybody. But I would like the div to be of infinite height.

Answer (score 2):

First of all , margin: 0 auto; is used to center elements , it is also not possible to make a page with infinite height , but you can maximize it's height by using

```css
.body{
    text-align:center; /* IE Center trick because margin:0 auto; will not work. Go go IE! :D */
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 1080px;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 100%;
    /* DO NOT RESTORE THE ALIGNMENT HERE --- */
}

.wrapper .div {
    margin:0 auto; /*center the elements */
    text-align: left; /* restore the alignment */
    min-height: 100%; /* maximize the height; make it 1080 pixels */
    height: 100%; /* not necessary but i like to add it as well :) */
}
```

margin: 0 auto;  0 means that there will be 0 space between the division and the element thats  right above it and **auto** will adjust the right spacing to be the same with the left one :)

It goes like this margin: top right bottom left;

Comment: Hmmm, I have no idea why I thought 0 auto would make in continous. Could swear I heard it somewhere... Hm, is there a way to make it a guarantee so the user would see the white wrapper from top to bottom of his screen, while not making the scroller bar appear for the person then?

Comment: Actually, the 'height: 100%' should help it render the way it's supposed to in IE6.